# css text on many line

Tags: css, angular

I have a div that contains an svg image and a paragraph and I want that if my paragraph is too long that it comes back to the line. My problem is that the return to the line does not work

```
  <a [routerLink]="[menuitem.path]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'" class="item-menu-content">
    <svg-icon class="icon-menu" [src]="menuitem.icon!"></svg-icon>
    <p>{{menuitem.title}}</p>
  </a>


.item-menu-content {
  max-width: 200px !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Are these class styles the only ones that apply to your element? If not you should add all relevant styles applied to it. To start, `a` elements are `inline` by default, which means the `width` will not apply to it. You can try for example with `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to see if it helps (additional styles might be necessary depending on what you want)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the issue. Comes back to the line? is that a visual problem? maybe put a stackblitz example?

If the issue is that the svg is taking the whole line it is probably because it is a block element and you placing it outside the p tag

```css
.item-menu-content {
  max-width: 200px !important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  flex: none;
  fill: cornflowerblue;
  stroke: 2px;
}
```

```html
    <a class="item-menu-content">
    
    <p><svg class="icon" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg> {{menuitem.title}}</p>
  </a>
 
 
 <a class="item-menu-content">
    <svg class="icon" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
    <p> {{menuitem.title}}</p>
  </a>
```